# My Jakarta EE9 project works only on Payara server. Why?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, payara

My hello-world "Jakarta EE 9" project, hosted at https://github.com/iubar/hello-jaxrs
works only in Payara 5.2021.2 but not in Tomcat 10 nor in Wildfly 23.0.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using the _WildFly 23 Preview EE 9_ distribution or the normal distribution (Jakarta EE 8)? Tomcat 10 does not implement JAX-RS: did you add Jersey 3 or another JAX-RS implementation to the runtime?

Comment: Hi Piotr,
1) I'm using the WildFly 23 final, I got it from the main download page. I don't know anything else, I thought it supported EE 9.
2) When you say "runtime" do you mean server runtime or war dependencies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Wildfly 23, there are two versions available (cf. [download page](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/)):

- *Jakarta EE Full & Web distribution* is a full Jakarta EE **8** server. This is basically a rebranding of Java EE 8.
- *WildFly 23 Preview EE 9* is a full Jakarta EE **9** server. Only this version uses the new `jakarta.*` namespace.

Regarding Tomcat 10: Tomcat implements only five (Servlet, JSP, EL, Websocket and JASPIC) specification of Jakarta EE 9 (cf. [version list](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)). Since the Servlet API interacts with other specifications (e.g. Annotations, JPA and JAX-WS) Tomcat will behave correctly if you add the spec and implementation JARs to the *common* classpath (`$CATALINA_HOME/lib`).

The link to your project is broken, but I guess it uses JAX-RS. Therefore you have two options:

- you can have a special version of your application that ships with [`jersey-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/3.0.1), [`jersey-container-servlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/3.0.1) and probably an [InjectionManager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject).
- you can use [TomEE 9](https://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html), which is a full Jakarta EE 9 server based on Tomcat 10.

Comment: Now my sample poject has public visibility (https://github.com/iubar/hello-jaxrs)

Comment: The project works fine with OpenLiberty 21.0.0.4-beta and Payara 5.2021.2.
(I think they are both the first version to support EE9)

Comment: I have tried to add the "jakarta.jakartaee-api-9.0.0.jar" to tomcat10/lib/ but without success.

Comment: I think I will go with OpenLiberty, it has a very rich documentation and it's maven friendly.
Thank you Piotr.

Comment: `jakarta.jakartaee-api-9.0.0.jar` contains just the API: you also need the implementation of all Jakarta EE specifications. In your case you just need to add [`jersey-container-servlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/3.0.1) to the Maven dependencies and your application will work on Tomcat 10.

Comment: I have followed your advice, but Tomcat 10 returns the "javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init()'" error which indicates an unsupported dependency version or a versions clonfict. So I ditched Tomcat in favor of OpenLiberty. Thank you for support. Bye